# Image is not appended into img id container after user has clicked on button

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, sorting, random

***Functionality:***

User will need to answer 1 simple question with 4 options. Each option is appended with a different image. Hence, a new page with the appended image will be displayed depending on which option that the user has chosen.

Therefore, this is the general flow :

Page A-> displays a question with 4 options for the user to select. Depending on which option that the user selects. It will navigate to Page B and display the image that is associated with the option selected by the user.

***What has been done:***

I have created a `<div>` page for the question and 4 options as well as a 2nd `<div>` page that will show the appended image depending on the option that the user has selected.

This is the code that I have done:

```js
var random_Question,
  random_BrandIndex,
  optionList,
  PrintSelectedOffer;

//Append array of images to list container in alphabetical Order
var x = 0,
  number = 0;
var printOptionFrame = "";

//Brand Offers
var Outlook_list = [];


//Set Array bank of Questions
var QuestionOrder = ["A?", "B?", "C?", "D?", "E?"];

//Set Array bank of Answers
var ChoiceOrder = [
  ["Shpinge", "Vacation", "Sav", "Donate"],
  ["Responsibles", " Foreign ", "Gourmet ", "Martial "],
  ["A ue Sea", "Rn Grass", "Dark F Trees", "WaterfallRainbow"],
  ["Cooking", "Traling", "Playing", "Shg"],
  ["Fabok", "Insram", "Snhat", "Seie?"]
];

//Print Array
var PrintOrder = [
  ["A01", "A02", "A03", "A04"],
  ["A03", "A05", "A04", "A06"],
  ["A02", "A03", "A06", "A04"],
  ["A04", "A05", "A03", "A01"],
  ["A03", "A04", "A02", "A06"]
];

function Start() {
  idleTime = 0;

  $("#Start").fadeOut();
  $("#QuestionPage").fadeIn({
    complete: function() {

      //Show Original Answer Point
      $("#Pointer_1").show();
      $("#Pointer_2").show();
      $("#Pointer_3").show();
      $("#Pointer_4").show();
      //Show Question and Answers
      showQuestion();
    }
  });
}

function showQuestion() {

  //Randomised Question Array List
  random_Question = Math.floor(Math.random() * QuestionOrder.length);
  //Push randomised question array into empty array reference
  Outlook_list.push(random_Question);
  console.log("Outlook_list:" + "[" + Outlook_list + "]");

  $("#GamePageOption_1").attr("class", "original_brightness");
  $("#GamePageOption_2").attr("class", "original_brightness");
  $("#GamePageOption_3").attr("class", "original_brightness");
  $("#GamePageOption_4").attr("class", "original_brightness");

  $("#Option_selected_1").hide();
  $("#Option_selected_2").hide();
  $("#Option_selected_3").hide();
  $("#Option_selected_4").hide();

  $("#Page_question").html(QuestionOrder[random_Question]);

  optionList = ChoiceOrder[random_Question];

  $("#GamePageOption_1").html(optionList[0]);
  $("#GamePageOption_2").html(optionList[1]);
  $("#GamePageOption_3").html(optionList[2]);
  $("#GamePageOption_4").html(optionList[3]);
}


function select_option(flag) {
  idleTime = 0;

  //Play with brightness of selected option

  if (flag == 1) {
    $("#Option_selected_1").show();
    $("#GamePageOption_2").attr("class", "decrease_brightness");
    $("#Pointer_2").attr("class", "decrease_brightness");
    $("#GamePageOption_3").attr("class", "decrease_brightness");
    $("#Pointer_3").attr("class", "decrease_brightness");
    $("#GamePageOption_4").attr("class", "decrease_brightness");
    $("#Pointer_4").attr("class", "decrease_brightness");
  } else if (flag == 2) {
    $("#Option_selected_2").show();
    $("#GamePageOption_1").attr("class", "decrease_brightness");
    $("#Pointer_1").attr("class", "decrease_brightness");
    $("#GamePageOption_3").attr("class", "decrease_brightness");
    $("#Pointer_3").attr("class", "decrease_brightness");
    $("#GamePageOption_4").attr("class", "decrease_brightness");
    $("#Pointer_4").attr("class", "decrease_brightness");
  } else if (flag == 3) {
    $("#Option_selected_3").show();
    $("#GamePageOption_1").attr("class", "decrease_brightness");
    $("#Pointer_1").attr("class", "decrease_brightness");
    $("#GamePageOption_2").attr("class", "decrease_brightness");
    $("#Pointer_2").attr("class", "decrease_brightness");
    $("#GamePageOption_4").attr("class", "decrease_brightness");
    $("#Pointer_4").attr("class", "decrease_brightness");
  } else if (flag == 4) {
    $("#Option_selected_4").show();
    $("#GamePageOption_1").attr("class", "decrease_brightness");
    $("#Pointer_1").attr("class", "decrease_brightness");
    $("#GamePageOption_2").attr("class", "decrease_brightness");
    $("#Pointer_2").attr("class", "decrease_brightness");
    $("#GamePageOption_3").attr("class", "decrease_brightness");
    $("#Pointer_3").attr("class", "decrease_brightness");
  }

  setTimeout(function() {

    $("#QuestionPage").fadeOut();
    $("#Description").fadeIn({
      complete: function() {

        //show outlook description
        printOptionFrame = PrintOrder[optionList];
        console.log("printOptionFrame: " + printOptionFrame);
        $("#DescriptionBlock").attr('src', printOptionFrame).show();
      }
    });
  }, 1000);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="QuestionPage" align="center" style="position:absolute; width:1080px; height:1920px; background-repeat: no-repeat; z-index=2; top:0px; left:0px; margin:auto;">

  <!--MainStart Image-->
  <img id="Background" src="lib/image/Background.png" style="position:absolute; top:0px; left:0px; margin:auto;" />

  <!-- Question -->
  <div id="Page_question" style="position:absolute; font-family:AgendaSemiBold; z-index:3; top:515px; left:180px; margin:auto; color:#FFFFFF; font-size:30px; width:800px;"></div>

  <!-- Answer List -->
  <div id="GamePageOption_1" style="position:absolute; font-family:AgendaBold; z-index:3; top:854px; left:317px; margin:auto; color:#FFFFFF; font-size:25px; width:750px; text-align: justify;"></div>
  <div id="GamePageOption_2" style="position:absolute; font-family:AgendaBold;  z-index:3; top:986px; left:317px; margin:auto; color:#FFFFFF; font-size:25px; width:750px; text-align: justify;"></div>
  <div id="GamePageOption_3" style="position:absolute; font-family:AgendaBold;  z-index:3; top:1098px; left:317px; margin:auto; color:#FFFFFF; font-size:25px; width:750px; text-align: justify;"></div>
  <div id="GamePageOption_4" style="position:absolute; font-family:AgendaBold;  z-index:3; top:1214px; left:317px; margin:auto; color:#FFFFFF; font-size:25px; width:750px; text-align: justify;"></div>

  <!--Original Option Point -->
  <img id="Pointer_1" src="lib/image/OriginalOptionPoint.png" style="display:none; position:absolute; z-index:4; top:836px; left:180px; margin:auto;" />
  <img id="Pointer_2" src="lib/image/OriginalOptionPoint.png" style="display:none; position:absolute; z-index:4; top:962px; left:180px; margin:auto;" />
  <img id="Pointer_3" src="lib/image/OriginalOptionPoint.png" style="display:none; position:absolute; z-index:4; top:1077px; left:180px; margin:auto;" />
  <img id="Pointer_4" src="lib/image/OriginalOptionPoint.png" style="display:none; position:absolute; z-index:4; top:1193px; left:180px; margin:auto;" />

  <!-- Selected Option Point -->
  <img id="Option_selected_1" src="lib/image/SelectedOptionPoint.png" style="display:none; position:absolute; z-index:5; top:836px; left:180px; margin:auto;" />
  <img id="Option_selected_2" src="lib/image/SelectedOptionPoint.png" style="display:none; position:absolute; z-index:5; top:962px; left:180px; margin:auto;" />
  <img id="Option_selected_3" src="lib/image/SelectedOptionPoint.png" style="display:none; position:absolute; z-index:5; top:1077px; left:180px; margin:auto;" />
  <img id="Option_selected_4" src="lib/image/SelectedOptionPoint.png" style="display:none; position:absolute; z-index:5; top:1193px; left:180px; margin:auto;" />

  <!-- Selection of answer -->
  <img src="lib/image/transparent.png" class="transparentBg" style="position:absolute; z-index:6; top:854px; left:0px; margin:auto; color:#FFFFFF; font-size:25px; width:1080px; height:80px;" onclick="select_option(1);" />
  <img src="lib/image/transparent.png" class="transparentBg" style="position:absolute; z-index:6; top:986px; left:0px; margin:auto; color:#FFFFFF; font-size:25px; width:1080px; height:80px;" onclick="select_option(2);" />
  <img src="lib/image/transparent.png" class="transparentBg" style="position:absolute; z-index:6; top:1098px; left:0px; margin:auto; color:#FFFFFF; font-size:25px; width:1080px; height:80px;" onclick="select_option(3);" />
  <img src="lib/image/transparent.png" class="transparentBg" style="position:absolute; z-index:6; top:1214px; left:0px; margin:auto; color:#FFFFFF; font-size:25px; width:1080px; height:80px;" onclick="select_option(4);" />

  <button class="MainReset" onclick="Reset()"></button>

</div>

<div id="Description" align="center" style="position:absolute; width:1080px; height:1920px; background-repeat: no-repeat; display: none; z-index=7; top:0px; margin:auto;">

  <!--Video Div-->
  <!-- <div id="UOB_DescriptionVideo" style="position:absolute;"></div> -->

  <!--MainStart Image-->
  <img id="DescriptionBackground" src="lib/image/Description.png" style="position:absolute; top:0px; left:0px; margin:auto;" />

  <img id="DescriptionBlock" style="position:absolute; top:0px; left:0px; margin:auto;">
</div>
```

***Issue:***

When I clicked on the option, no element from  the array of `PrintOrder`  is displayed on Page B. As in the img id of `DescriptionBlock` is not displayed. Hence, I am unable to call the associated image after I have clicked on the option from Page A.

Hence, I would need some assistance and what have I done wrong?

Comment: Hi can you provide a plunker link or something? Coz one thing i can see is you only hide the imgs with "decrease_brightness" but no resets for it when any other options is selected. Also i cant see where u handle printorder when option is selected. All in all, i think you can use a loop to build most of it up and reduce your code :) Please provide plunker so i can have a go at it

Comment: Is this a minimal example and did you debug your code?

Comment: You're never setting `printOptionFrame`

Comment: @Tibrogargan, what do you mean by I am never setting printOrderFrame?

Comment: @WickStargazer, I did not provide the option for any reset as I am not allowing user to have re-selection privilege. Hence, when user selects an option, a delay is set just right to show what user has selected and then the question page will navigate to description page where the image associated to the option will be displayed. I don't really understand what do you mean by the part where "handle printorder when option is selected".

Comment: @Luke please provide a plunker. and it will be solved in minutes :D

Comment: @Luke you set `random_Question` to a random number.  Then you set `optionList` to one of the elements of `ChoiceOrder`.  Those elements are arrays (which is fine).  Then you do this: `printOptionFrame = PrintOrder[optionList]`, which effectively something like this: `printOptionFrame = PrintOrder["A ue Sea,Rn Grass,Dark F Trees,WaterfallRainbow"]`, which is `undefined`.  Technically you do set printOptionFrame, but you set it to `undefined`.  I think maybe you mean `printOptionFrame = PrintOrder[optionList[flag]]`. but your code is badly organised so I can't tell.

Comment: @Luke, https://plnkr.co/edit/KPdciiZk6jojsgMhoB6S?p=preview here is aplunker, I substiute the complete: function() with a call later. Does it work that way according to u?

Comment: @WickStargazer this is my plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/Qf2Dawq4Nu3za931r5xI?p=catalogue. sorry, I was trying to do up my plunker to show you

Comment: @Luke My bad, you never even call `Start()`, so pretty much nothing is going to work

Comment: @Tibrogargan sorry, i didnt edit that part. Have changed to Start() but it aint working as it should be too

Answer (score 0):

I don't really think this is much of an answer, since I don't really know what you're trying to do.  It does however reduce the size of your code somewhat and perhaps progresses you along somewhat.  It looks like you're trying to change what is shown by `DescriptionBlock` but I suspect you're pulling from the incorrect array.

```js
var random_Question;
var random_BrandIndex;
var optionList;
var PrintSelectedOffer

var printOptionFrame = "";

//Brand Offers
var Outlook_list = [];

//Set Array bank of Questions
var QuestionOrder = ["A?", "B?", "C?", "D?", "E?"];

//Set Array bank of Answers
var ChoiceOrder = [
  ["Shpinge", "Vacation", "Sav", "Donate"],
  ["Responsibles", " Foreign ", "Gourmet ", "Martial "],
  ["A ue Sea", "Rn Grass", "Dark F Trees", "WaterfallRainbow"],
  ["Cooking", "Traling", "Playing", "Shg"],
  ["Fabok", "Insram", "Snhat", "Seie?"]
];

//Print Array
var PrintOrder = [
  ["A01", "A02", "A03", "A04"],
  ["A03", "A05", "A04", "A06"],
  ["A02", "A03", "A06", "A04"],
  ["A04", "A05", "A03", "A01"],
  ["A03", "A04", "A02", "A06"]
];

function Start() {
    $("#Start").fadeOut();
    $("#QuestionPage").fadeIn({
        complete: function() {
            //Show Original Answer Point
            $("img[id^=Pointer_").show();
            //Show Question and Answers
            showQuestion();
        }
    });
}

function showQuestion() {
    //Randomised Question Array List
    random_Question = Math.floor(Math.random() * QuestionOrder.length);
    //Push randomised question array into empty array reference
    Outlook_list.push(random_Question);
    console.log("Outlook_list:" + "[" + Outlook_list + "]");

    $("div[id^=GamePageOption_").attr("class", "original_brightness");
    $("img[id^=Option_selected_").hide();
    $("#Page_question").html(QuestionOrder[random_Question]);

    optionList = ChoiceOrder[random_Question];

    for(var i = 0; i < optionList.length; i++) {
        $("#GamePageOption_"+(i+1)).html(optionList[i]);
    }
}

function select_option(flag) {
    //Play with brightness of selected option

    for(var i = 1; i <= optionList.length; i++) {
        if (flag == i) {
            $("#Option_selected_"+i).show();
        } else {
            $("#GamePageOption_"+i).attr("class", "decrease_brightness");
            $("#Pointer_"+i).attr("class", "decrease_brightness");
        }
    }

    setTimeout(function() {
        $("#QuestionPage").fadeOut();
        $("#Description").fadeIn({
            complete: function() {
                //show outlook description
                printOptionFrame = PrintOrder[random_Question][flag - 1];
                // guess 2: printOptionFrame = ChoiceOrder[random_Question][flag - 1];
                console.log(`printOptionFrame: ${printOptionFrame}`);
                $("#DescriptionBlock").attr('src', printOptionFrame).show();
            }
        });
    }, 1000);
}
document.addEventListener( "DOMContentLoaded", Start, false );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="QuestionPage" align="center" style="position:absolute; width:1080px; height:1920px; background-repeat: no-repeat; z-index=2; top:0px; left:0px; margin:auto;">

  <!--MainStart Image-->
  <img id="Background" src="lib/image/Background.png" style="position:absolute; top:0px; left:0px; margin:auto;" />

  <!-- Question -->
  <div id="Page_question" style="position:absolute; font-family:AgendaSemiBold; z-index:3; top:515px; left:180px; margin:auto; color:#FFFFFF; font-size:30px; width:800px;"></div>

  <!-- Answer List -->
  <div id="GamePageOption_1" style="position:absolute; font-family:AgendaBold; z-index:3; top:854px; left:317px; margin:auto; color:#FFFFFF; font-size:25px; width:750px; text-align: justify;"></div>
  <div id="GamePageOption_2" style="position:absolute; font-family:AgendaBold;  z-index:3; top:986px; left:317px; margin:auto; color:#FFFFFF; font-size:25px; width:750px; text-align: justify;"></div>
  <div id="GamePageOption_3" style="position:absolute; font-family:AgendaBold;  z-index:3; top:1098px; left:317px; margin:auto; color:#FFFFFF; font-size:25px; width:750px; text-align: justify;"></div>
  <div id="GamePageOption_4" style="position:absolute; font-family:AgendaBold;  z-index:3; top:1214px; left:317px; margin:auto; color:#FFFFFF; font-size:25px; width:750px; text-align: justify;"></div>

  <!--Original Option Point -->
  <img id="Pointer_1" src="lib/image/OriginalOptionPoint.png" style="display:none; position:absolute; z-index:4; top:836px; left:180px; margin:auto;" />
  <img id="Pointer_2" src="lib/image/OriginalOptionPoint.png" style="display:none; position:absolute; z-index:4; top:962px; left:180px; margin:auto;" />
  <img id="Pointer_3" src="lib/image/OriginalOptionPoint.png" style="display:none; position:absolute; z-index:4; top:1077px; left:180px; margin:auto;" />
  <img id="Pointer_4" src="lib/image/OriginalOptionPoint.png" style="display:none; position:absolute; z-index:4; top:1193px; left:180px; margin:auto;" />

  <!-- Selected Option Point -->
  <img id="Option_selected_1" src="lib/image/SelectedOptionPoint.png" style="display:none; position:absolute; z-index:5; top:836px; left:180px; margin:auto;" />
  <img id="Option_selected_2" src="lib/image/SelectedOptionPoint.png" style="display:none; position:absolute; z-index:5; top:962px; left:180px; margin:auto;" />
  <img id="Option_selected_3" src="lib/image/SelectedOptionPoint.png" style="display:none; position:absolute; z-index:5; top:1077px; left:180px; margin:auto;" />
  <img id="Option_selected_4" src="lib/image/SelectedOptionPoint.png" style="display:none; position:absolute; z-index:5; top:1193px; left:180px; margin:auto;" />

  <!-- Selection of answer -->
  <img src="lib/image/transparent.png" class="transparentBg" style="position:absolute; z-index:6; top:854px; left:0px; margin:auto; color:#FFFFFF; font-size:25px; width:1080px; height:80px;" onclick="select_option(1);" />
  <img src="lib/image/transparent.png" class="transparentBg" style="position:absolute; z-index:6; top:986px; left:0px; margin:auto; color:#FFFFFF; font-size:25px; width:1080px; height:80px;" onclick="select_option(2);" />
  <img src="lib/image/transparent.png" class="transparentBg" style="position:absolute; z-index:6; top:1098px; left:0px; margin:auto; color:#FFFFFF; font-size:25px; width:1080px; height:80px;" onclick="select_option(3);" />
  <img src="lib/image/transparent.png" class="transparentBg" style="position:absolute; z-index:6; top:1214px; left:0px; margin:auto; color:#FFFFFF; font-size:25px; width:1080px; height:80px;" onclick="select_option(4);" />

  <button class="MainReset" onclick="Reset()"></button>

</div>

<div id="Description" align="center" style="position:absolute; width:1080px; height:1920px; background-repeat: no-repeat; display: none; z-index=7; top:0px; margin:auto;">

  <!--Video Div-->
  <!-- <div id="UOB_DescriptionVideo" style="position:absolute;"></div> -->

  <!--MainStart Image-->
  <img id="DescriptionBackground" src="lib/image/Description.png" style="position:absolute; top:0px; left:0px; margin:auto;" />

  <img id="DescriptionBlock" style="position:absolute; top:0px; left:0px; margin:auto;">
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, I am trying to change what is shown by "DescriptionBlock". I am trying to append the element from ` var PrintOrder =[]` to the img tag for id ="DescriptionBlock". The element in `var PrintOrder = ` is displayed based on what option user clicked from 'var ChoiceOrder'. I am still stucked though. At this point, I reference to this "printOptionFrame = PrintOrder[Outlook_list];" and when I console.log printOptionFrame, it is showing the element that is associated to the ChoiceOrder  selected but it is still not showing for  img id "DescriptionBlock"

Comment: I have just tried but in the console.log, printOptionFrame is returning an undefined result

Comment: not sure what help I can provide, it is quite hard to tell how your script is meant to work, so I have no idea what that value should be or where it should come from

Comment: Basically, this is what my script should achieve:

Comment: Basically, this is what my script should achieve: <div>id =page_question </div> will display the random question from the question array: var questionorder. The choice array: var choiceorder  will be appended to the four  <div> id = gamepageoption_*. And when useer clicks on the any of the 4 options that is displayed from the array pf var choiceorder, the associated image  from array var printorder will be displayed in the <img> id=descriptionblock. Therefore, printoptionframe should return the result of the inner element of var printorder based on the inner element of array  var choiceorder

Comment: There is no way to "return the result of the inner element of var printorder based on the inner element of array var choiceorder".  `PrintOrder` is not an associative array and all that `ChoiceOrder` holds is strings.  It's not even apparent what the current question is supposed to be since you just have an array of questions.  Is supposed to be first or last?  Perhaps the worst thing: I don't have any of your images so I don't even know if what I do is correct.  I've updated the answer so printOptionFrame is not undefined - but no idea if it's correct.

Answer (score 0):

i switched the

```
  $("#Description").fadeIn({
      complete: function() {

        //show outlook description
        printOptionFrame = PrintOrder[optionList];
        console.log("printOptionFrame: " + printOptionFrame);
        $("#DescriptionBlock").attr('src', printOptionFrame).show();
      }
    });
```

with

```
 $("#Description").fadeIn(function() {

    console.log(optionList.indexOf(optionList[flag-1]));
    //show outlook description
    printOptionFrame = PrintOrder[optionList.indexOf(optionList[flag-1])][optionList.indexOf(optionList[flag-1])];
    console.log("printOptionFrame: " + printOptionFrame);
    $("#DescriptionBlock").attr('src', printOptionFrame).show();
    $("#Description").append("<div>"+printOptionFrame+"</div>")
```

});

here is the plunker [https://plnkr.co/edit/KPdciiZk6jojsgMhoB6S?p=preview](https://plnkr.co/edit/KPdciiZk6jojsgMhoB6S?p=preview9)

the second page shows now. Is that what you r looking for?

FYI .. You can change your data structure to be more understandable, since i am not understading the relat-ability of it.something like

```
    var QuestionOrder = {"A?":{
  ChoiceOrder: ["Shpinge", "Vacation", "Sav", "Donate"],
  PrintOrder: ["A01", "A02", "A03", "A04"]
}, 
"B?":{
   ChoiceOrder: ["Responsibles", " Foreign ", "Gourmet ", "Martial "],
  PrintOrder: ["A01", "A02", "A03", "A04"]
}, 
"C?":{
 ChoiceOrder: ["A ue Sea", "Rn Grass", "Dark F Trees", "WaterfallRainbow"],
  PrintOrder: ["A01", "A02", "A03", "A04"]
}, 
"D?":{
  ChoiceOrder: ["Cooking", "Traling", "Playing", "Shg"],
  PrintOrder: ["A01", "A02", "A03", "A04"]
}, 
"E?":{
  ChoiceOrder:  ["Fabok", "Insram", "Snhat", "Seie?"],
  PrintOrder: ["A01", "A02", "A03", "A04"]
}};
```

Then you can do something like

```
function select_option(keyValue)
{
   var Choice = QuestionOrder[keyValue];
   alert(Choice.PrintOrder);
}
```

Same goes with printing questions. And you can loop it or do a lot with JSON.
Or you can also go to do a multi-dimensional Array.

@Tibrogargan Also provided the correct way to loop through your array to print out the questions. Should be more readable and maintainable for future uses

Hope i answered your question :)

Comment: I have just seen what you have done. You appended the '<div>YES!</div>` to the `<div> id = "Description</div>"`, however, I am still unable to show the array of " var PrintOrder = [[.....],[.....],[....],[....]]". I have managed to get the console log to show all the elements in the array but am unable to get the individual element that is appended to the individual option

Comment: @Luke i see your issue. your array index is not matching with the parameters. It should be number indixes not value of the other arrays. Anyways i suggest change it to json for a better readable code :)

Comment: will you able to show me please? or is there a way to go about with the current setup to reference with the element index in the PrintOrder array?

Comment: @Luke hi, sorry for the late reply. I have update the plunker and updating my answer as well :) One thing, why are you changing the attribute of the img src, is the optionframe suppose to be an image?

Comment: the elements in array PrintOrder are different, and furthermore each element is actually an image. Therefore, when user clicks on different element in the array ChoiceOrder, the associated element in PrintOrder will be displayed

Comment: as shown in question code snippet that I have uploaded for  array "var ChoiceOrder" and array "var PrintOrder". There are are multiple sub- elements within the main element. Hence, Element A in array choiceOrder when clicked will show the image element A01 in array PrintOrder..etc..etc. Hence, that is the reason why attribute of the img src needs to be changed.

Comment: so did inanswet the question by using indexof? that would help get the value to show correctly

Comment: I have just tried. IndexOf is showing the correct value based on the indices of the array for ChoiceOrder. The console.log for PrintOrder is returning all 4 sub-elements within the main element.

Comment: meaning I have  an array for ChoiceOrder = [["1","2","3","4"], ["a,"b","c","d"]]; and PrintOrder = [["a1","a2","a3","a4"], ["ba,"bb","bc","bd"]];, so when i clicked option1,console log  for  `console.log(optionList.indexOf(optionList[flag-1]));` will return me 0 and console.log for `console.log("printOptionFrame: " + printOptionFrame);`  will return me "a1". However, at this point the cosole log is returning me "["a1","a2","a3","a4"]" and hence, nothing is still shown for the img src. apologies, this is very confusing for me

Comment: you just have to do this then.
PrintOrder[optionList.indexOf(optionList[flag-1])][optionList.indexOf(optionList[flag-1])]
Because you want the inner index as well.

Comment: Thats is what i have done.  That is my following: `printOptionFrame = PrintOrder [optionList.indexOf (optionList [flag-1])];` but it is still showing the behaviour thay i have stated. Displaying all the elements within sub-array. Or am i missing out something

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127037/discussion-between-wickstargazer-and-luke).